# How to update p:selectOneRadio value through component binding

Tags: jsf, primefaces, binding, selectoneradio

I have bound a p:selectOneRadio component as below,

```
<p:selectOneRadio binding="#{bean.maritalStatusRadio}" value="#{bean.maritalStatus}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.maritalStatusList}" /> 
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.handleChangeInMaritalStatus}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

But I am unable to update its value from backing bean class.

```
SelectOneRadio maritalStatusRadio; 
    public void handleChangeInMaritalStatus() {
            String currentValue =String.valueOf(maritalStatusRadio.getValue());

            if(!currentValue.equals(MARITAL_STATUS_MARRIED)) {
                maritalStatusRadio.setValue(MARITAL_STATUS_MARRIED);

            }

    }`
```

Comment: How have you bound the component?

Comment: Show us your code so we could help you.

Comment: Yes  like this

<p:selectOneRadio binding="#{bean.maritalStatusRadio}" value="#{bean.maritalStatus}"   >
         <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.maritalStatusList}" />
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.handleChangeInMaritalStatus}" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>

Comment: How can I change its value in handleChangeInMaritalStatus listener method ?

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 0):

Your listener method is not the place to change your select value. It's for doing whatever you need when the user changes selected option in the view.

If you want to change the value selected you simply need to change the value assigned to your bound field, in this case bean.maritalStatus. You can do it in many places (including youtr listener if required).

Usually on preRenderView method is the place to initialize a select default value.
On your view:

```
  <f:metadata>
    <f:event
      type="preRenderView"
      listener="#{bean.initializeForNew}" />
  </f:metadata>
```

On your bean:

```
 public void initializeForNew() throws ModelException {
    if (!isPostBack()) {//only on loading
      bean.maritalStatus = getDefaultMaritaStatus();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="radioButton" binding="#{nominee.maritalStatusRadio}" value="#{nominee.prospective.maritalStatus}"  disabled="#{disabled}" >
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.maritalStatusList}" />
                                    <p:ajax update="radioButton" event="change" listener="#{nominee.handleChangeInMaritalStatus}" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
It worked for me I was not updating p:selectOneRadio in  p:ajax
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake now I have edited my question